# Ruby Array get split

Tags: ruby, arrays, split, put, gets

I need to remove the vowels from a string.

I have tried something like:

```
str = gets
str.split(//)
```

make an array, and then

```
 A1 = ['a', 'e', 'u', 'y', 'i', 'o']
 str-A1 
 str.to_s
 p str
```

But I don't know how to put it together, to remove the vowels from a string.

Comment: What do you want? join back to a string?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I need to remove the vowels from a string

Answer (score 3):

```
gets.gsub(/[aeiou]/i, '').chomp
```

or, a bit more easy

```
a = gets.delete 'aeiouAEIOU'
a.gsub("\n",'')
```

You can verify this answer by running above code at http://repl.it/languages/Ruby.

Comment: In the question, `gets` is a function to get input from the STDIN, not a string literal.

Comment: +1 I suggest removing the `comp` part, though. Don't see it in the question. And the `gsub` will not just remove the final `\n`.

Comment: Accordingly to the 1st and 2nd solutions I had put `chomp` and `gsub("\n",'')`  because it return result string including this `\n` so to get proper result I put them..

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple bit of code which filters vowels from a string that has been read from stdin/console:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

s = gets
sa = s.split(//)
vowels = 'aeiouy'.split(//)

puts sa.delete_if{|a| vowels.include?(a)}.join('')
```

My `vowels` is functionally equivalent to your `A1` ... though easier to read (less punctuation cluttering up the line).  Note that `.split()` returns an array from the string being split.  Also these are not *sets* and thus there is no overloading of the - (minus operator) to provide set differences.  (This seems to be what you were expecting and that won't work here).

Note that this example is converting the inputs and the list of vowels to arrays ... on the tacit assumption that you'd want to do other array handling on the aside from the simple filtering shown.  It would be more terse to keep them both as strings (as shown in other answers to this question).